# Recovery of transistor wired as diode

Tags: diodes, bjt, recovery

[image]

It's a simple question. What's the turn-off time of this "diode" and does it have a recovery time when turning off?

Since the transistor does not get into saturation I think it should be the same as turning it off normally, so pretty fast. The transistor is [D44H8](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/d44h-d.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Most transistors, and especially power transistors, exhibit long base-storage times that limit maximum frequency of operation in switching applications, unless clamped**, **such as in this circuit with Vce clamped by Vbe** ( or with a Schottky diode B-C clamp or a Baker's dual diode clamp etc). In storage time tests Vbe is switched from Vbe .0.6 at some Vce(sat)/Ibe(sat)-10 to Vbe = -500 mV ( industry standard) whereas in this question Vbc is = 0 by design**

> does it have recovery time when turning off?

Yes. But it will be less than the Recovery time is in the datasheet since the B-C diode capacitance reduces somewhat from 0.7V to 0V and pF reduces greatly for Vbc = - Vcc approx.  with inverse voltage yet -500 mV (standard test) for Vbe to Vce storage test times.

Not that the D44 and D45 differ in \$C_{cb},f_T,t_D+t_R,t_F \text{ yet } t_S~\$ is not affected with both = 500 ns.

This is tested with Vbe= -0.5V after Ic/Ib=10 using Ib= 0.5A from the bottom of page 2 in the ON spec.

From nominal values in fig's 5, [6] and 7, [8] for D44, [D45] **this means "Storage Time = 500ns" is measured at Ic=5A, Ib=500mA 25'C ;**
Vce[sat]=  150, [275] mV
Vbe(sat) = 940, [960] mV

Yet  when Vce=Vbe HFE is not 10 nor is current gain as high as hFE @ Vce=1000 mV (std test condition Vce=1V) but something in between so Ib is much lower and thus will have faster response time than Is @ 5A because Ib will be more like 2 to 3% of Ic rather than 10%. (Ic/Ib=10) yet the storage energy in the cloud capacitance layer E= 1/2CV^2 so the bulk capacitance in B-E will have the same voltage as Vce @ 5A but more Miller effect from Ccb @ hFE >>10.

If anyone has more to add or subtract. pls edit.

**Edit** (vangelo): I think it does deserve a direct comparison (signal x power BJT) to illustrate and I think it should not be posted as a separate answer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: TY @Vangelo ...you are a good collaborator

Comment: Interesting comparison between power transistor and BC547, 3055 has double the IC but much longer turn off time. I guess I'll have to test it with real components. Basically I need a diode that conforms well to the usual exponential equation (like a transistor does, but unlike most diodes), and that also turns off without making a fuss, and that can take several amps.

Comment: Diode capacitance and Rs is inverse with Pd rating but in a nonlinear way so the RC storage effect is constant for different variants of the same size but different for major sizes.

Comment: This got me wondering, would using a transistor like a diode like this be a good replacement for a Schottky clamp in really high speed circuits? Edit: yes, if you want low reverse biased current https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/using-a-transistor-as-a-diode

Answer (score 6):

This should actually be only a comment

CircuitLab transient analyzer shows that you are right. There's no such thing as storage time - not at least when the transistor is Cicuit Lab's version of 2N3904.  Here's a circuit with 1N4148.

Signal V2 is bipolar square wave 5V peak:

[image]

[image]

The diode conducts to reverse direction about 10 nanoseconds. Transistor turns off substantially faster with the same signal and load:

[image]

[image]

The reverse conduction starts to decay as soon as the polarity is reversed, there's no full reverse conduction period (= no storage time). Schottky-diodes have the same property. Except they have about 50% lower voltage drop.

Transistor's BE junction unfortunately stands only a few volts of reverse voltage, so this may be not so good in high voltage circuits.

Not asked: The output voltage to the load seems to be about -5,7V when V2 jumps to -5V. That can look surprising. It's not. The carrier cloud in the semiconductor is like a charged capacitor which has minus pole towards the load. When V2 jumps to negative there's -0,7V in series with V2.

The peak which occurs when V2 jumps to +5V is the same to another direction. The semiconductor capacitances have got bigger voltages during the minus polarity period of V2. Transistor seems to have much bigger capacitance than diode 1N4148,

Comment: A significant effort being put into simulation and explanations, maybe it's been worth to reveal a simulator used (it seems CircuitLab's is used), and also try and find d44h8's spice model, switching to the other simulator if necessary

Comment: @V.V.T ok. I inserted the simulator to the text.

Answer (score 3):

> does it have a recovery time when turning off?

Yes. The transistor will not turn off until the concentration of minority carriers in the base drops significantly.

> Since the transistor does not get into saturation I think it should [turn off] pretty fast.

Yes. Because the transistor is not in saturation, there will be less minority carriers in the base, and it will turn off quicker than a transistor in saturation. However, there is still a recovery time. It is just smaller than that of a saturated transistor.